# Silverlight combobox acting like menu

Tags: silverlight, drop-down-menu

I want to modify silverlight combobox behavior. I want to open dropdown by mouse entering to combobox but not clicking, that iseasy to do when handling MouseEnter event and seting IsDropDownOpen property to true. But the issue is how to close dropdown when mouse leaves dropdown area and combo itself. Any suggestions. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you use `Expander` from Silverlight Toolkit with `ItemsControl`

Video: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/creating-ui/control-basics/silverlight-toolkit-creating-a-toolkit-expander